# Proper script placement for function call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function called `getQuery` which I call from my HTML, but for some reason the browser can't find the script. I have tried putting it in the `<head>` and `<body>` but doesn't seem to want to work.

Can someone tell me the proper placement of the script for this web-page, or how the script needs to be loaded?

This is how I call the function:

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" noresize name="mainFrame" target="_top" id="reg-frame"
        src="javascript:getQuery('registrationPage')"></iframe>
```

The error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: getQuery is not defined`

Comment: What does the function do?

Comment: A little googling should give you more then enough direction. for example: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Comment: You cant use a javascript function as the `src` of an iframe. Its not where you're placing the function, its how you're trying to use it!

Comment: You _can_ however invoke a function on page load that _sets_ the `src` of an `<iframe>`.  ie `window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('reg-frame').src = getQuery('registrationPage') }`

Comment: Define "can't find the script" and "doesn't seem to want to work".  How does it fail?  What error do you get?

Comment: `src="javascript:getQuery('registrationPage')"` really doesn't make sense. What is `getQuery('registrationPage')` doing anyway?

Comment: @FelixKling I have seen it used for `href` before, so figured I'd try it with `src`. I have a function to parse the URI and get the query string. so the URL will look something like `www.example.com?registrationPage=www.somepage.com`

Comment: The error that I am getting is `Uncaught ReferenceError: getQuery is not defined` which in my mind means that it is trying to execute the function but doesn't know where the script is.

Comment: @Adjit: When used in `href`, it simply means that the code in there is executed when the link is clicked. It's a poor man's `click` event handler. It is *not* used to generated the URL dynamically. So in your case, it would simply execute the code when the `iframe` is loaded, but that's it. It doesn't do anything with the return value of the function. Your code is equivalent to simply doing `<script>getQuery('registrationPage')</script>`.

Comment: @FelixKling ok, that makes sense. I parse the url `onpopstate`. I guess what I should then do is add to that event the distribution of the parsed query to it's proper elements. Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `src` attribute from the HTML:

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" noresize name="mainFrame" target="_top" id="reg-frame"></iframe>
```

Then you can define your function whenever:

```
function getQuery(url) {
    return url; // Maybe do some parsing here?
}
```

And then assign the source of the frame:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("mainFrame");
frame.src = getQuery('registrationPage');
```

You can experiment with this on [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/1krubkfv/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" noresize name="mainFrame" target="_top" id="reg-frame"
onload="this.src=getQuery('registrationPage');" 
src="">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Is the `load` event triggered if `src` is empty? Why are you having `javascript:` there? It's completely useless (and confusing) at that position.

Comment: `onload="this.src=getQuery('registrationPage');"`

Comment: I expect the function returns the url of the registration page. should work i have used it myself

Answer (score -2):

Would this work?

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" noresize name="mainFrame" target="_top" id="reg-frame">
    <script src="javascript:getQuery('registrationPage')"></script>
</iframe>
```